# Default schema is not working with select query in asp classic

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-server-2012, database-schema, adodb

I'm having problems with default schema and sql in asp classic. First, I have a database 'MyDatabase', this database has the schema 'MySchema' (all tables are into this schema), also there is a user 'jdoe' with privileges over 'MyDatabase' and with a default schema 'MySchema', 'jdoe' is not sysadmin.
'jdoe' can execute from management studio the following query without errors:

```
SELECT columnOne FROM MyTable
```

The same query but from an .asp page can not find MyTable:

```
Dim query
query = "SELECT ColumnOne FROM MyTable"
```

Asp pages are using ADODB.Command and user 'jdoe'. The query returns results if I specify explictly the schema:

```
Dim query
query = "SELECT ColumnOne FROM MySchema.MyTable"
```

I searched the web but all answer say the same: Asign a default schema to 'jdoe',but i did it and works with t-sql in the server or dabatase like stored procedures but not work with querys like I have in asp pages.

Does exist some special configuration?

thanks.

Comment: Did you change default schema this way? `ALTER USER MyUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = MySchema` if not try that and see if it works after that. Also verify that your are modifying correct user that you are connecting with from application.

Comment: Yes,I did it but only works with code on server, it's still not working from asp pages. I took care about user when assigning default schema.

Comment: so you are executing the iis/the application pool with the same Windows user you altered the Default Schema for?

Comment: I've resolved it!! I was using a sql server user and i configured this user but it didn't work. After i configured a windows user with the same configuration and it works!!.

Comment: If you solved it, please add an answer and click the checkmark to accept it - it's quite ok to answer your own questions here.

Comment: Ok. I already put my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

I don't know what happened, i change sql server user 'jdoe' by windows user(domain\user) and it works, i configured windows user the same way, assigning a default schema and with no sysadmin privileges. 
From asp pages i used a DSN with windows authentication and from IIS i configured website security directory to allow anonymous access and i used the same user i used in sql server.